# Using BigQuery to visualize high volume of points

Tags: google-bigquery, data-visualization, mapbox, geojson

At a certain scale of geographic data, it is useful to export the dataset to a png file in order to lay it on top of a map if there are lots of points. For example, if there are 50M points, if we are just interested in visualizing that data (without sampling, re-sampling, or aggregating), we could export that to a png and overlay that onto a map.

An example of this is done with MapD, a GPU database. For example, they will render the image server-side, https://www.omnisci.com/platform/core#native-geospatial-processing, and then send it back to the client:

```
blob:https://www.omnisci.com/3cf6df03-4809-4a6d-9b73-24c12c3fadb5
```

[image]

Is there any option to do something similar in BigQuery? What would be the suggested way to graph a larger number of geographic points/objects on a map (without going the short route of clustering: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers).

Comment: Would something like this help at all? (BigQuery's GIS functionality + viz) https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/gis-visualize

Comment: @GrahamPolley not really -- that limits to: `Geo Viz can only display up to 2,000 results on a map.`

Comment: That may be a soft limit than can be raised by Google. However, 50M is a lot though.

Comment: There is beta version of more scalable GeoViz, but it would not scale to 50 mln either: https://beta-dot-bigquerygeoviz.appspot.com/

Comment: @Michael neat, do you know what the hard (or soft) limits for that may be?

Comment: I think it is one page of BigQuery results, 10MB IIRC. 50k points should fit, don't fetch columns you don't use to reduce result size.

Comment: @David542 - 50M is definitely too much! would something around 200K made your case?

Comment: @Michael -- sure, then outside of GeoViz, which options are possible?

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery Geo Viz is the tool for visualization of geospatial data in BigQuery. However, as you already read in @GrahamPolley 's [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/gis-visualize) the limit is only 2,000 results.

So, currently, there is no way to visualize 50M points on a map using BigQuery and Geo Viz.

Off the top of my head, you could export the points from BigQuery and then visualize them with a visualization library of your preferred programming language. However, you would also need to invoke the Maps API so it’s not very feasible as it is like suggesting to develop your own Geo Viz tool.

I have created a feature request for you [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/134124372) which I recommend that you star to receive updates and comment to show that there is interest and provide some traction.

Another option would be to open a support case and ask for a higher limit, although I am not confident that you are going to be provided with, considering the nature of the limit.

Comment: What may be some alternatives then outside of the GeoViz solution to "visualize more points in a BigQuery dataset than Geo Viz can support" ?

Comment: @David542 I have edited my answer with more information.